# Ruby on Rails - How to arrange elements of array in particular order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-1.8.7

My array is:

```
[{:age=>28, :name=>"John", :id=>1}, {:name=>"David", :age=>20, :id=>2}]
```

Order:

```
[:id, :name, :age] or ['id', 'name', 'age']
```

The result should be:

```
[{:id=>1, :name=>"John", :age=>28}, {:id=>2, :name=>"David", :age=>20}]
```

P/s: I am using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.5

Thanks

Comment: Order is not maintained in Hash, of Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: If you want ordered hashes you'll need to upgrade to Ruby 1.9+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you cannot do that with Ruby 1.87 or prior. Here is one way to do that with Ruby 1.9+:

```
arr = [{:age=>28, :name=>"John", :id=>1}, {:name=>"David", :age=>20, :id=>2}]
order = [:id, :name, :age]

arr.map { |h| Hash[order.zip(h.values_at(*order))] }
  #=> [{:id=>1, :name=>"John", :age=>28}, {:id=>2, :name=>"David", :age=>20}]
```

In Ruby 2.0+, you can write:

```
arr.map { |h| order.zip(h.values_at(*order)).to_h }
```

I thought 1.8.7 went out with the steam engine.

Answer (score 2):

Order doesn't matter when it comes to hashes. You do not need to do that. Trust me.

What you're using is an `Hash` which, unlike `Array` doesn't care for positions. You only access the value by it's `Symbol` or *Key*.

So, there is no need of doing what you want to.

Comment: OP clearly requested to sort an array and you are talking about hashes.

Comment: OP is obviously talking about hashes too, if you read the question.

Comment: @ChrisHeald Yes, I misread a question as “sort an array by hash values.” My apologies.

Comment: I beg to differ. I have made good use of Ruby's maintenance of key insertion order in v. 1.9+.